# Problems with Android 4.1 loading external html using Phonegap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an Android application working with the latest version of Phonegap and Jquery Mobile. I haven't had any problems on Android 4.0.1 or below, but when I installed the app on Android 4.1, I got one issue. There is a section on the app where I have a XMLHttpRequest to load an external HTML. For some reason, on deviceready, the application gives me an alert telling me that the app cannot load the HTML. I don't know what's wrong. Any idea what's the problem? Why is it only happening on Jelly Bean?

Answer (score 1):

@User1608382,

Like Simon said, show us your code.

If you don't want to show us all your code, just strip out as much of your code as possible, try it again to see if you can reproduce the issue, and give us that minimal test case that still has the problem. A number of us have actual `4.1.1` devices we can test on.

Does DeviceReady even give you access to logcat? Since the service is still by invitation-only, I couldn't immediately browse its documentation.

Also, go to the bug tracker at [b.android.com](http://b.android.com) and search for `4.1 webview`

As you can see from those results, Android 4.1.x introduced a couple of problems for WebView, so hopefully your problem is listed in there already.

Comment: Sorry for not adding code, but I was sure that my problem was not on my javascript, css or html code. I knew that the problem was on the Android settings. That's why I didn't provide code. I was right. The android manifest was causing this issue. If you have android:targetSdkVersion=15 or android:targetSdkVersion=16. It causes all XmlHttpRequest to fail. Deleting that line on the AndroidManifest solved the problem. I only left the minSdk value.

Comment: No one was questioning your diagnosis. As evidenced with the official bug tracker at http://b.android.com , there are several bugs that were recently introduced with Android 4.1 on WebView (which is used by Phone Gap). We just thought you wanted to know exactly which bug was the culprit, so you could star the issue on the bug tracker and be notified if/when they ever fixed this issue. In either case, it doesn't seem like you need to know the answer and have moved on, which is fine.